# Lemmon Slider Auto Play only moves one then stops

Tags: jquery, slideshow, carousel

I'm using [Lemmon Juice slider](http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php) due to having variable width images and it works fine except that I can't get auto play to work. It moves one image then stops - this is when using `'slideToLast' :` true or '`infinite' : true`. Manual controls work as expected. Is there something I'm missing that would get this carousel to auto play infinitely and not just stop after moving one slide?

**html:**

```
<div id="slider1" class="slider">
  <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://domain.com/slide/image1.jpg"/>            

        <span class="caption">
         some caption here
        </span>

      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="http://domain.com/slide/image2.jpg"/>            

        <span class="caption">
         2nd caption here
        </span>

      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="http://domain.com/slide/image3.jpg"/>            

        <span class="caption">
         3rd caption here
        </span>

      </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
 // home page slider 
var sliderTimeout;
window.onload = function(){

    $( '#slider1' ).lemmonSlider({
         'infinite' : true
        /*'slideToLast' : true*/
    });

    // run
    sliderAutoplay();
    }
    // slider autoplay function
    function sliderAutoplay(){

        $( '#slider1' ).trigger( 'nextSlide' );
        sliderTimeout = setTimeout( 'sliderAutoplay', 1500 );

    }
    // pause slider function
    function sliderPause(){

        clearTimeout( sliderTimeout );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution after another cup of coffee. Turns out the documentation on that page is not 100% accurate. I did a view source to see how the autoplay slider was actually working.

The working jQuery for me is:

```
    window.onload = function(){

         // home page slider 
        $( '#slider1' ).lemmonSlider({ infinite: true });
        sliderAutoplay();
        $( '#slider3-play' ).click(function(){
            if ( sliderTimeout == null ){
                sliderAutoplay();
            }
            return false;
        });

// this part in original page, but I don't really need it
        $( '#slider3-pause' ).click(function(){
            clearTimeout( sliderTimeout );
            sliderTimeout = null;
            return false;
        });


    }
    // autoplay
    var sliderTimeout = null;
    function sliderAutoplay(){

        $( '#slider1' ).trigger( 'nextSlide' );
        sliderTimeout = setTimeout( 'sliderAutoplay()', 3500 );

    }
```

hope this helps someone out in the future.